# Error bars not visible in chart

Tags: vba, powerpoint, errorbar

I am trying to create both horizontal and vertical error bars in a chart in MS Powerpoint. While I am able to set the parameters for the error bars using VBA, the error bars are however not visible. When I manually check the error bars settings in the chart, the required settings are done. Below is the code I am trying:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideNumb).Shapes(ChartName).Chart.Select
With ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideNumb).Shapes(ChartName).Chart.SeriesCollection(2)
    .HasErrorBars = True
    .ErrorBars.Select
    .ErrorBar Direction:=xlY, Include:=xlErrorBarIncludeBoth, Type:=xlErrorBarTypeCustom, Amount:=100, MinusValues:=100
    .ErrorBar Direction:=xlX, Include:=xlErrorBarIncludeBoth, Type:=xlErrorBarTypeCustom, Amount:=100, MinusValues:=100
End With
With ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideNumb).Shapes(ChartName).Chart.SeriesCollection(2).ErrorBars.Border
    .LineStyle = msoLineSingle   
    .Color = RGB(0, 112, 192)
    .Weight = 1.5
End With 
With ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideNumb).Shapes(ChartName).Chart.SeriesCollection(2).ErrorBars
     .Select
     .Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
     .Format.Line.Style = msoLineSingle
     .Format.Line.Weight = 1.5
     .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 112, 192)
     .Format.Line.DashStyle = msoLineSysDash
     .EndStyle = xlNoCap
End With
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, though a bit crude, had a workaround the problem.

Created two similar series collection in the chart and applied the horizontal error bar plot on one and the vertical error bar plot on the second. Following is the code:

```
        ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideNumb).Shapes(ChartName).Chart.FullSeriesCollection(2).ErrorBar Direction:=xlY, Include:=xlBoth, Type:=xlFixedValue, Amount:=1000
        With ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideNumb).Shapes(ChartName).Chart.FullSeriesCollection(2).ErrorBars
            .EndStyle = xlCap
            With .Format.Line
                .Visible = msoTrue
                .DashStyle = msoLineDash
                .Weight = 2
                .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent1
            End With
        End With

        ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideNumb).Shapes(ChartName).Chart.FullSeriesCollection(3).ErrorBar Direction:=xlX, Include:=xlBoth, Type:=xlFixedValue, Amount:=1000
        With ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideNumb).Shapes(ChartName).Chart.FullSeriesCollection(3).ErrorBars
            .EndStyle = xlCap
            With .Format.Line
                .Visible = msoTrue
                .DashStyle = msoLineDash
                .Weight = 2
                .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent1
            End With
        End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove these two lines:

```
.HasErrorBars = True
.ErrorBars.Select
```

Comment: Tried doing this, but the same result. The settings are done but the bars are not visible.

Comment: What type of chart is it? I think it must be XY scatter.

Comment: I am using a 3D Bubble chart.